# cant flash my nodemcu esp8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, nodemcu, flash

So i wanted to flash my Nodemcu esp8266 v3.4 with esp8266 deauther code: [script-github](https://github.com/SpacehuhnTech/esp8266_deauther)
i did everything said. First i plugged in my nodemcu. Windows detected it and drivers for ch340 where already installed. I tried using the Nodemcu firmware programmer programm for flashing, but when starting flashing in the log there it was just stuck on "begin finding esp8266". then i tried using the arduino ide, again i did everything the github wiki said. but i got this:

```
Sketch uses 829464 bytes (79%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 32132 bytes (39%) of dynamic memory, leaving 49788 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
esptool.py v2.8
Serial port COM5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jakob\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\deauther\hardware\esp8266\2.7.5/tools/upload.py", line 65, in <module>
    esptool.main(cmdline)
  File "C:/Users/jakob/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/deauther/hardware/esp8266/2.7.5/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2889, in main
    esp = chip_class(each_port, initial_baud, args.trace)
  File "C:/Users/jakob/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/deauther/hardware/esp8266/2.7.5/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 237, in __init__
    self._port = serial.serial_for_url(port)
  File "C:/Users/jakob/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/deauther/hardware/esp8266/2.7.5/tools/pyserial\serial\__init__.py", line 88, in serial_for_url
    instance.open()
  File "C:/Users/jakob/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/deauther/hardware/esp8266/2.7.5/tools/pyserial\serial\serialwin32.py", line 78, in open
    self._reconfigure_port()
  File "C:/Users/jakob/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/deauther/hardware/esp8266/2.7.5/tools/pyserial\serial\serialwin32.py", line 222, in _reconfigure_port
    'Original message: {!r}'.format(ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'Ein an das System angeschlossenes Ger�t funktioniert nicht.', None, 31)
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1
```

Comment: always format printouts as code for readability